# Auto submit is not posting data to database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to post a file into a Blob. I have created a HTML form that automatically posts when A file is selected:

```
<form id="target" method="post" name="frmImage" class="frmImageUpload" action="./post.php">  
  <div id="pic1">
    <input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile" class="userfile"/>
  </div>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#pic1').click(function(){ 
    $('#userfile').trigger('click'); 
  });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#userfile').change(function() {
    $('#target').submit();
  });
</script>
```

When I select a file the script is navigating me to `post.php`. But it is not posting anything to the database.

Here is my post.php:

```
<?php
    include_once '../../../../includes/connect.php';
    include_once '../../../../includes/functions.php';

    sec_session_start();

    $correct = true;

    if(isset($_POST['userfile']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0) {
      $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
      $tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
      $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
      $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];
      $_SESSION['user_id'];

      $fp = fopen($tmpName, 'rb');
      $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
      $content = addslashes($content);
      fclose($fp);

        if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        {
          $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
        }

        $query = "INSERT INTO temp (user_id, content) VALUES (". $_SESSION['user_id'] .", '$content')";
        mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 
        $msg = "<br>File <b>$fileName</b> uploaded<br>";

    }
    else
    {
        $msg = "<br>File <b>$fileName</b> not uploaded<br>";
    }
?>
```

Does someone know what is wrong with my script?

Edit:
the error message received are the following:

> Notice: Undefined index: userfile in (...) on line 12

and

> Notice: Undefined variable: fileName in in (...) on line 37

Comment: getting errors ??

Comment: I get a notice. `Notice: Undefined index: userfile in (...) on line 12` and `Notice: Undefined variable: fileName in  in (...) on line 37`

Comment: this notice means, input data in not encoded,

Answer (score 2):

According to your comment, you are getting undefined index notice due to `multipart/form-data`,

You need to use [`enctype="multipart/form-data"`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp) in your `<form>` as:

```
<form id="target" method="post" name="frmImage" class="frmImageUpload" action="./post.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

**Second,** you need to define `$fileName` as `$fileName = '';` at top level declaration, otherwise you will get another undefined variable notice

You need to declare it before this line:

```
if(isset($_POST['userfile']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0) {
```

**as:**

```
$fileName = '';
if(isset($_POST['userfile']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0) {
```

**Third,** mysql_* is deprecated extension and closed in PHP7, i suggest you to use [`mysqli_*`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

**Fourth,** you code is wide open for SQL injection, preventing for SQL injection, you can use PDO.

**Fifth,** and dont know what is it? `$_SESSION['user_id'];`

**Some useful links:**

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

[Are PDO prepared statements sufficient to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: It solved the notice on line 12. But it is stil not posting into my database. I still get `Notice: Undefined variable: fileName in in (...) on line 37`

Comment: @John: bcox u need to define this variable at top level `$fileName`

Answer (score 2):

You form must include `enctype='multipart/form-data'` attribute. This attribute is required to upload files.

It'll look like:

```
<form id="target" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' name="frmImage" class="frmImageUpload" action="./post.php">  
  <div id="pic1">
    <input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile" class="userfile"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

I recommend you using `move_uploaded_file`. [See more](https://www.php.net/manual/features.file-upload.post-method.php#example-388).

Comment: It solved the notice on line 12. But it is stil not posting into my database. I still get `Notice: Undefined variable: fileName in in (...) on line 37`

Comment: @John, you do not need to check `isset($_POST['userfile'])`

Comment: @devpro, then, in this case `is_uploaded_file`

Comment: its enough `if(isset($_POST['userfile']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0) {` ???? isnt it?

Comment: @devpro it is not about checking if we have or not a file, it is about security. Please, read: https://www.php.net/manual/function.is-uploaded-file.php